# Bootstrap striped table - row border overlaps with closest rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, less, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm running into problems doing something that is supposed to be extremely simple... Adding a 1px top&bottom border to a bootstrap table row (tr), when hovered. 
The table is striped but I don't think it matters (not using bootstrap's `table-striped` class but I checked and it happens when using it, too). It's an Angular app.

**The problem**: the 1px top border is not displayed because the previous row, which is not hovered, has a 1px bottom border which overlaps the hovered row. The border of the previous row is displayed while the border of the hovered row is not. If I change the hovering borders to 2px, it's displayed (1px is behind the previous row's bottom border, the second px is displayed).

I could have used a "previous sibling" selector (opposite of the `+` selector) if there was any... to remove the previous row's bottom border;

How can give a 1px top&bottom border to a hovered table row?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ug9df67q/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of the border-bottom on all of them and it looks fine:

```
tr td {
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
}

tr:hover td {
    border: solid 1px red !important;
}
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/asbjsvtu/

Comment: good idea to put the borders on the td rather than tr. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you right, it would be good if you make a fiddle about it.
But if I get you right, you could just add `padding-top: 1px;` and `padding-bottom: 1px` (or if it already has a padding on it just add 1px to the top and bottom) to the table row, when it's hovered.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```css
.table tr:hover td {
  border-top: 1px solid red !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
}
.table thead tr th {
  border: none !important;
}
.table tbody:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```